# Git pull on ubuntu server as non-root user not working because of file permissions

Tags: git, ubuntu-16.04, bitbucket.org

I have a web app whose code is owned by root user on a remote Ubuntu server.  The app code is saved under /var/www/.  Most of the files and subdirectories for the code are also owned by root user.  When I try to pull the latest changes to the code from my bitbucket repository, I get the following error: "insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects."    Most of the sub directories and files in the project's .git/objects folder don't provider write permission for non-root users.   What's the best approach to resolve this error and ensure a successful git pull? 1) change user for all these files/folders in .git/objects or 2) change permissions for all these files/folders to allow write access to everyone or 3) something else?

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to have special purpose users and groups to do this sort of stuff — commonly one per service such as Apache HTTPD, PostgreSQL, NTPD, Docker etc. — with otherwise absolutely minimal access. That way there's minimal risk to the rest of the system.

Specifically, I think this would be a secure approach:

1. There should be a user and group specifically for the web server. The web server should be running as that user. I believe this is often "www", so we'll go with that for now.
2. Create a new user like "deployer" or something in the "www" group.
3. Make it the owner of all the files: `chown -R deployer:www /var/www`.
4. Restrict group access to read and traverse directories: `chmod -R g=rX /var/www`.
5. Make sure only the deployer can access at least the .git directory: `chmod -R go= /var/www/.git`. Add any other files which should never ever be served via the web.

Comment: So what specific changes would you recommend making to the ubuntu environment?  I ask as a newbie.

Comment: To make sure I understand, create a new group called 'www', add a new user called 'deployer' to group 'www', make user 'deployer' owner of the entire project code listed under /var/www/,<project> (<project> folder contains all of the code)?  Or should I make group 'www' owner of the entire project code?  Also, what chmod code pertains to step 4 in your suggestion - 750 or something else?  What about permissions to files under /var/www/<project>?  Also, don't understand what your step 5 does.  Can you please elaborate?  Any changes to config files to reflect ownership change of project code?

Comment: There should *already* be a user/group pair which was created when installing the web server. I can't know which it is, because I don't know which web server you run. I don't think there's a numeric representation for the `X` permission; see `man chmod`.

Comment: I'm running a Ubuntu server with Rackspace.  Does that help?